# Reading temperature of CPU cores using C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, cpu

I'm working on an application that can print the usage of each CPU core using C++ by reading proc/stat and parsing it, but I'm having problem with getting temperature, the problem is that different applications show we different amount of CPU cores. when I launch **system monitor** it shows me 12 cores, **btop** also shows me 12 cores same as my **stat/proc**. but when I'm using something like **sensors** to get temperature it shows temperature for only 6 cores, same thing for **/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/** it shows me temperature only for 6 cores. I don't know where's the problem, how am I supposed to get temperature of all 12 cores? I tried looking at **btop source code** because it displays temperature for all 12 cores, the problem is that I am terrible at reading source code so I weren't able to find anything useful :(.

Comment: Maybe your CPU only has 6 sensors because its a 6C 12T and not a 12C 24T. My point is virtual cores usually don't have their own sensor because it doesn't really make sense since its the same pipelines.

Comment: @drescherjm so how btop and system monitor are able to print their temperature?

Comment: They may not have accurate readings. They may be measuring different sensors that are external to the CPU.

Comment: The temperature may change between readings, if they aren't always the same for temperatures of two logical cores on the same physical core.  It may just figure out which core is the sibling and check that one if there isn't core temperature for the current logical core.